# Stop Wt C++ function while it's running

Tags: c++, wt

I'm using Wt (witty) C++ framework and stuck with an issue how to stop a function from running. If button open_doors_button is clicked, it activates a function doors_open_all, which takes a long time to complete.

The problems appears if the user would like to stop this function from running.
I added a function stop_doors_open_all, which changes a global boolean to stop the previous function. The issue is that func stop_doors_open_all will be called after func doors_open_all is finished, making the stop function useless.

```
    Wt::WPushButton *open_doors_button = new Wt::WPushButton("open all");
    container_box->addWidget(open_doors_button);
    open_doors_button->clicked().connect(boost::bind(&Servicemode::doors_open_all, this));

    Wt::WPushButton *stop_doors_button = new Wt::WPushButton("stop opening");
    container_box->addWidget(stop_doors_button);
    stop_doors_button->clicked().connect(boost::bind(&Servicemode::stop_doors_open_all, this));
```

Comment: You will need to run your slow function in its own thread if you don't want to block the thread that responds to Wt events.  Multithreading is what you're describing.

Comment: That might just cut it, thanks!
However, do you know how to connect boost::bind with a thread?

Comment: I've posted my response to your original question as a proper answer.  It looks like you have a new question now, and it should be posted as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to run your slow function in its own thread if you don't want to block the thread that responds to Wt events. Multithreading is what you're describing.